# Unable to refer to jpg in bitmap path parameter

Tags: c#, bitmap, jpeg

I have a jpg in a folder in my project. I want to make a bitmap out of it but it says my path is invalid when I try to refer to the jpg.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAWIG.jpg

Console Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Drawing.IntSecurity.UnsafeGetFullPath(String fileName)
   at System.Drawing.IntSecurity.DemandReadFileIO(String fileName)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
   at ConsoleImageCompare.Compare.differance(String img1, String img2) in c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleImageCompare\ConsoleImageCompare\Compare.cs:line 22
   at ConsoleImageCompare.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Please paste your code here as text and not as a screenshot.

Comment: Use `Image.FromFile()` when instating the bitmap.

Comment: Thanks, now I just need to figure why it can't find the jpg despite the path seems correct. var bmp  = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\\Image\\test.jpg"));

Comment: @Kitson88 Why? `Image.FromFile()` is just a wrapper for the `Bitmap(String path)` constructor that returns the result as the less-accurate `Image` superclass instead of the actual `Bitmap` type the loaded object is.

Comment: I was not aware at the time that you could instantiate a `Bitmap` using any other image file formats other than `.BMP`. I can see that this is the case and is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Kitson88 `Bitmap` is not related to the .bmp file format; it is just the basic implementation of the abstract `Image` class. Generally, all `Image` objects you'll ever handle in .Net will actually be Bitmap class. And while "it's just a wrapper" was a bit of oversimplification on my side, both functions basically just ask GDI+ to "open this file and detect if there's a known image format in it", and that always returns a `Bitmap` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is by default console application points to the bin/debug folder.So you need to go up two level to get the file

```
@"../../image/<Your File name>"
```

Use this

Comment: This is a bad idea though. It will no longer apply once the application is actually released. A much better idea is to actually copy your resources to the output folder.